# Finding $ \lim_{x \to \pi} \operatorname{sgn}[ \tan x]$

Tags: calculus, limits

> Find the limit $$ \lim_{x \to \pi} \operatorname{sgn}[ \tan x] $$, where $[\cdot]$ represents greatest integer function.

By intuition, we say that  the limit do not exist bcz the L.H.L and R.H.L are not equal... But is there any theoretical proof of this.

Edit:-

[image]

From graph of tanx we say that if x approaches to π from LHS it gives a negative value but if it approaches from RHS then it give a positive value.

Comment: If you can verify that the one-sided limits don't agree, that _is_ a theoretical proof that the limit does not exist. Can you edit your post to show your work for the one-sided limits?

Comment: Put $\tan x=y.$ Then our limit is $\displaystyle \lim_{y\rightarrow 0}\sig(y)=$

Comment: @Abhishek Kumar: Thanks for putting in the effort to show your work (+1). Since $\tan(x)$ is negative (but close to $0$) as $x$ approaches $\pi$ from the left, the limit in question from the left is _______ ? Similarly, since $\tan(x)$ is positive (but close to $0$) as $x$ approaches $\pi$ from the right, the limit in question from the right is _______ ? If stuck, try some actual values for $x$, to get a sense of what's going on.

Comment: Thanks ... I understand what to do next

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at it like this. Consider $h>0$.

The LHL is essentially:

$$\lim_{h\to 0^+} \tan(\pi-h)$$

Now expanding $tan(\pi-h)$ as $\frac{\tan(\pi) -\tan(h)}{1+\tan(\pi)\tan(h)}$, we have

$$\lim_{h \to 0^{+}} -\tan(h)$$

Now since $h \to 0^+$, $\tan(h) > 0$ and $-\tan(h) < 0$.

Therefore,

$$\lim_{h \to 0^+} [-\tan(h)] = -1$$

Therefore,

$$\lim_{h \to 0^+} sgn([-\tan(h)]) = -1$$

Similarly we can do for the RHL which comes out to be $1$. Therefore the limit doesn't exist.